# How to properly setup webpack config to include common chunks used in multiple page (and entry) app?

Tags: javascript, webpack, config, chunks

Imagine having below structure of html files:

```
./home.html
./settings.html
./contact.html
```

Also having below js files

```
./nav.js <-- common - used in all html files
./home.js <-- used only in home.html, below follow the same rule
./settings.js
./contact.js
```

And some modules from `node_modules`:

`"jquery"`
`"moment"`

that are being imported as if when required:

```
./home.js
import $ from "jquery";
(...)
```

I have setup webpack to have each entry point as each file name. Now what would be the way to include common js files such as `./nav.js" into each file?

```
entry: {
  home: "./resources/js/sections/home.js",
  settings: "./resources/js/sections/settings.js",
  (...)
} 
(...)
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
}
```

// Option A

Import raw `nav.js` like another module in every subpage (`home.js`, `contact.js`, `settings.js`)

```
import nav from ./nav.js
nav();
```

// Option B

create another entry for `./nav.js` and manually add bundled `nav.js` to each html alongside other bundled files.

```
entry: {
  (...)
  nav: "./resources/js/sections/nav.js"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [HtmlWebPackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) in order to append scripts dynamically to your HTML pages.

First of all install the plugin:

```
npm install html-loader html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then use the config:

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    nav: './resources/js/sections/nav.js',
    home: './resources/js/sections/home.js',
    settings: './resources/js/sections/settings.js',
    contact: './resources/js/sections/contact.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // folder where all tranformed files will be placed
  },
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      use: [{ 
        loader: "html-loader", 
        options: { minimize: true } 
      }]
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    // create an instance of HtmlWebPackPlugin for every page of a multipage website
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./resources/html/home.html", // take html from this path
      filename: "./home.html", // name it 'home.html' and insert to the root of output folder
      chunks: ['nav', 'home'] // insert dymamically nav.js and home.js to home.html
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./resources/html/settings.html",
      filename: "./settings.html",
      chunks: ['nav', 'settings']
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./resources/html/contact.html",
      filename: "./contact.html",
      chunks: ['nav', 'contact']
    }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell the HtmlWebPackPlugin will create a new html file, which is going to overwrite my current html, that is full of skeleton html  tags and a lot of content??

Comment: It will keep your html file as it is but will append scripts at the end of body tag

Comment: Thank you, I guess that would be the way to do it, but my html files are also templated via php, therefore no `<body>` tag is present.

Comment: Have you tried the configuration? Maybe Webpack will append the scripts at the end of HTML if there's no body. Good luck!

Comment: Hi again, it did output it at the end of the file which is not quite correct but never mind... It also did not include any other files that home.html is sharing vendors with - I mean `vendors~home` and `vendors-home-contact` etc. But hey, I learned something new :)